# как работать с gson с вложенными объектами?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

сделал такой код.

```
            val data = inStream.readText()

            var gson = Gson()
            var root = gson.fromJson<Curs>(data,Curs::class.java)
            return root.getPrice(currency)
```

и вот класс Curs

```
class Curs {
    inner class data {
        inner class BTC {
            inner class USD {
                var price : Double = 0.0
            }
            inner class RUB {
                var price : Double = 0.0
            }
        }
    }
    fun getPrice ( currency : String ) : String {
        when (currency) {
            "USD" -> return this.data().BTC().USD().price.toString()
            "RUB" -> return this.data().BTC().RUB().price.toString()
            else -> return "error $currency"
        }
    }
}
```

В инете везде примеры простые и нигде не показывается вложенные json данные. Мне нужно распарсить такой json.

```
{"status":{"timestamp":"2020-10-10T23:36:19.511Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":7,"credit_count":1,"notice":null},"data":{"BTC":{"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","slug":"bitcoin","num_market_pairs":9490,"date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channels"],"max_supply":21000000,"circulating_supply":18513062,"total_supply":18513062,"is_active":1,"platform":null,"cmc_rank":1,"is_fiat":0,"last_updated":"2020-10-10T23:35:23.000Z","quote":{"RUB":{"price":865809.8341713237,"volume_24h":1748827526362.0588,"percent_change_1h":-0.9616285,"percent_change_24h":1.50010355,"percent_change_7d":5.80169311,"market_cap":16028791140223.434,"last_updated":"2020-10-10T23:35:58.000Z"}}}}}
```

причем есть варианты с RUB и USD и мне надо сделать так, чтобы парсить и RUB и USD.

Comment: Одни классы и не одного поля. Конечно будут проблемы

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена с созданием такого класса.

```
class Curs {
    var data : DATA = DATA()
    inner class DATA {
        var BTC : btc = btc()
        inner class btc {
            var quote : QUOTE = QUOTE()

            inner class QUOTE {
                var USD : usd = usd()

                var RUB : rub = rub()

                inner class usd {
                    var price : Double = 0.0
                }
                inner class rub {
                    var price : Double = 0.0
                }
            }

        }
    }
    fun getPrice ( currency : String ) : String {
        when (currency) {
            "USD" -> return this.data.BTC.quote.USD.price.toString()
            "RUB" -> return this.data.BTC.quote.RUB.price.toString()
            else -> return "error $currency"
        }
    }
}
```